# Java jnlp exception

Tags: java, applet, jnlp

I am beginner in the **Java Applets** area and following a book now, I did step by step all the instructions that are written but I got error during compilation time. I am trying to use the **JNLP ServiceManager** , when the applet starts it must ask for a permission but in my case it gives me error:

```
 javax.jnlp.UnavailableServiceException: uninitialized
    at javax.jnlp.ServiceManager.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at LoadImageAndScale.init(LoadImageAndScale.java:48)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:434)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and here is my code:

```
import javax.jnlp.FileContents;
import javax.jnlp.FileOpenService;
import javax.jnlp.ServiceManager;
import javax.jnlp.UnavailableServiceException;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by taner on 2016-01-25.
 */
public class LoadImageAndScale extends JApplet {
    private ImageIcon image;
    private JPanel scaleJPanel;
    private JLabel percentJLabel;
    private JTextField scaleInputJTextField;
    private JButton scaleChangeJButoon;
    private double scaleValue = 1.0;

    public void init() {
        scaleJPanel = new JPanel();
        percentJLabel = new JLabel("scale percent: ");
        scaleInputJTextField = new JTextField("100");
        scaleChangeJButoon = new JButton("Set Scale");

        scaleJPanel.add(percentJLabel);
        scaleJPanel.add(scaleInputJTextField);
        scaleJPanel.add(scaleChangeJButoon);
        add(scaleJPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        scaleChangeJButoon.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        scaleValue = Double.parseDouble(
                                scaleInputJTextField.getText()) / 100.0;
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
        );

        try {
            FileOpenService fileOpenService = (FileOpenService) ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.FileOpenService");
            FileContents contents = fileOpenService.openFileDialog(null, null);

            byte[] imageData = new byte[(int) contents.getLength()];
            contents.getInputStream().read(imageData);
            image = new ImageIcon(imageData);

            add(new DrawJPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        } catch (UnavailableServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class DrawJPanel extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            double spareWidth = getWidth() - scaleValue * image.getIconWidth();
            double spareHeight = getHeight() - scaleValue * image.getIconHeight();

            g.drawImage(image.getImage(),
                    (int) (spareWidth) / 2, (int) (spareHeight) / 2,
                    (int) (image.getIconWidth() * scaleValue),
                    (int) (image.getIconHeight() * scaleValue), this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the service implmentation 'javax.jnlp.FileOpenService' available in your dependencies or in JAR META-INF ?

Comment: *"..beginner in the Java Applets area and following a book now.."* Skip the study of applets, they have become irrelevant.  More formally: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson just from curiosity, what is the alternative of it, thank you :)

Comment: *"..what is the alternative of it(?)"* Of an app. available off the net that can scale an image? Use JWS to launch a frame directly from a link. Most browsers don't support embedded applets now - at all.